# How to remove two lines from terminal output

Tags: bash, terminal, echo

Given that two lines have been printed out in the terminal, is it possible to delete both of them so they may be replaced with two new lines?

I know you can use \r to replace 1 line (well, to move the cursor to the start of the line), but is there any way of doing this for the line above?

As an example, I'm running a program for computing the eigenfunctions of the Schrodinger equation and I want to keep an eye on how my variables are changing as it's being run, so I'd like an output like:

```
Param 1: xxxxxxx  
Param 2: xxxxxxx
```

So I'd have the two parameters on two lines so they can be easily read and they'd be updated on each iteration of the program's matching function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `cuu1` terminal capability allows you to go up a line. Pass it to `tput` in order to read the character sequence from the terminfo/termcap database, and then `echo` it twice.

```
echo -e '123\nabc\n'"$(tput cuu1)$(tput cuu1)"'*\n*'
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Can't believe I've never heard of tput before. This'll help a whole lot more than with just this project.

Comment: Android Terminal has no `tput` unfortunately.

Answer (score 7):

You could also use `$(tput cuu 2)` instead of `$(tput cuu1)$(tput cuu1)`

-- ***Aesthir***

Comment: That's pretty much what I ended up doing after looking up the man page for tput.

Comment: does not work on macos